# Debian - Docky compiz settings?

Tags: crunchbang, compiz, docky

I really like Docky and I wanted that genie 'magic lamp' effect. So I Googled it and it said I needed Compiz settings and to install it I did

```
$ sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

it wasn't found so I did some more researching and I can't find it. The closest thing I can find to something compiz was compiz-fusion something. I tried it and it was not it.

So does anybody know where I can get this package? I'm running Crunchbang.

Comment: Compiz shouldn't be needed for this, you probably found an old post. Compiz-fusion is a fork of compiz, compizconfig-settings-manager is the settings app of compiz. None of these should be needed. What exactly is this magic lamp effect you are after?

Comment: @terdon the one you'd get with OS X while minimizing a program.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install ccsm`.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with Docky, but I think the problem is that you don't have the Gnome desktop and it appears Docky is run within that desktop environment. Crunchbang has Openbox for a window manager but no desktop environment.

See here for a bit more on desktop environments versus window manager: http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2007/12/18/flipping-the-linux-switch-desktop-environments-vs-window-manag/

Take a look at https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/docky/ for other possible dependencies you might be missing.

Comment: Docky is working perfectly for me, it's just I cannot get this effect as it needs compizconfig-settings-manager